# How to center a graph using ScrollView - Scrolling by Pixel

Tags: swiftui

I am using a ScrollView to show a Graph in order to horizontally scroll it. Problem is that I need to center it when the view initially loads.

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    VStack {
                        Graph()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 2, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300, alignment: .center)
    }
}


fileprivate struct Graph: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in

            let rect = geometry.size

            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
            }
            .stroke(Color.black)

            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
            }
            .stroke(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

ScrollViewReader provides the scrollTo function but it works if the ScrollView contains more views with their own identifier so it's not an option in this case.

How can I scroll the graph by pixel in order to center it programmatically?

Comment: Did my answer help? If not, let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. Yes! It actually did.

Answer (score 2):

(I think) Using `ScrollView` is unnecessary since you have only one `View`. You may use `DragGesture` to move `Graph()` on  the x-axis. It also helps you center `Graph()` on the `x-axis` when it appears.

#### 1.

Offset `Graph()` by half of the screen's width. In order to do so, define a new `@State` property, set it to `-(geometry.size.width / 2)`, and use `.offset()` view-modifier.

#### 2.

Use `DragGesture()` to move on the `x-axis`. You need to keep track of the last offset too.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    @State var lastOffset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Graph()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 2, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                        .offset(x: offset)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    offset = -(geometry.size.width / 2)
                    lastOffset = offset
                }
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                        offset =  lastOffset + value.translation.width
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        lastOffset = offset
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```